# Setting Slider Value

Tags: python, vpython

Firstly, I don't have much experience with Python. All I'm trying to do is get this slider to give me a variable `temp` that I can actually use. As it is the damn thing either tells me there's a data type mismatch or simply doesn't report where the slider is. Here's the code, (and yes I know my cube is a sphere)

```
import pygame
import time
from visual.controls import *
from math import *

def setdir(direction): 
    cube.dir = direction

def red(value):
    red = temp * 0.04

def blue(value):
    blue = red - 2

def green(value):
    green = red - 2

def spherecolor(value): 
    cube.color = (red, 0, 0)
    if cube.color == color.red:
        t1.value = 0 
    else:
        t1.value = 1

def setrate(obj): 
    cuberate(obj.value) 

def cuberate(value):
    cube.dtheta = 2*value*pi/1e3
temp=1
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
x = sin(a)
y = sin(b)
z = sin(c)
w = 350

display(x=w, y=0, width=w, height=w, range=1.5, forward=-vector(0,0,1), newzoom=1)

c = controls(x=0, y=0, width=w, height=w, range=60)

s2 = slider(pos=(-50,20), width=7, length=100, axis=(1,0,0), text='Temperature', max=100., value=temp)
s1 = slider(pos=(-50,40), width=7, length=100, axis=(1,0,0), text='Angular Velocity', action=lambda: setrate(s1))

cube = sphere(color=(temp/25, (temp/25)-2, (temp/25)-2), material=materials.rough, pos=(x,y,z))
sphere.velocity = vector(x,y,z)

setrate(s1) 
setdir(-1) 

side = .4
thk = 0.3
s2 = 2*side - thk
s3 = 2*side + thk

cube.p = vector (0.5,-0.3,0.0)
t=0
dt=0.1
while True:
    rate(100)
    cube.rotate(axis=(0,1,0), angle=cube.dir*cube.dtheta)
    t = t + dt
    cube.pos = cube.p*sin(t)/10
    if not (side > cube.x > -side):
        cube.p.x = -cube.p.x
    if not (side > cube.y > -side):
        cube.p.y = -cube.p.y
    if not (side > cube.z > -side):
        cube.p.z = -cube.p.z
```

Comment: You might try trimming your code down until you can find a small section that doesn't work as you expect.  I see you have two sliders.  Do either of them work?  Maybe try removing one and just getting one to work before getting both to work.

Comment: One does work. s1 works fine, s2 does nothing.

Comment: hmmm.. that's pretty important information you might want to include with the question.  Notice the different parameter names you're sending to each one; maybe that has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After creating s2, you then reassign s2:

```
  s2 = 2*side - thk
```

Change this s2 to something else.